# Evicting connections to a read-only node in a cluster from the connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp, amazon-aurora

My application connects to a fail-over cluster of two *MySQL* 5.6 (actually, *Amazon Aurora*) instances. The active node is always write-accessible, while the passive one is running in [`read_only`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only) mode (this is different from the canonical *MySQL* fail-over cluster, where all slave nodes are write-accessible by default). *Amazon RDS* provides a symbolic DNS name which always points to the IP address of the active *MySQL* node.

During the fail-over process, the former master is restarted in `read_only` mode, while the former passive node becomes write-accessible and is promoted to master. Also, the DNS records are changed, so that the DNS name of a cluster is now pointing to the new master node.

Even if I totally disable DNS caching on Java side (via `sun.net.inetaddr.ttl` or `networkaddress.cache.ttl`), OS-specific DNS caching is still effective, so after the database fail-over I end up having my DBCP pool full of connections to the read-only *MySQL* instance. These connections are [`valid`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid-int-), i. e. they have been obtained **after** the fail-over completed but **before** the DNS cache expired. Additionally, none of such connections has [`readOnly`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isReadOnly--) flag set, so I can't tell whether I'm talking to a read-only instance until I execute some DML, which is when [`ER_OPTION_PREVENTS_STATEMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_option_prevents_statement) comes in all its glory. Even if I explicitly put a connection to a read-write mode by calling [`setReadOnly(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly-boolean-) and set the [`readOnlyPropagatesToServer`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,629670,629670) flag, this only results in a driver sending `SET SESSION TRANSACTION READ WRITE` to the server, which doesn't lead to any exception thrown.

I would like to solve this problem with as little application logic affected as possible. This could be accomplished if there were a way to treat a connection to a read-only instance as an invalid/closed connection (i. e. evict it from the pool).

Can I have a [*validation query*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#validationQuery) such as `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'read_only'` with an additional logic tied to it? Is it possible to affect the pool's behavior w.r.t a connection based on which scalar value the validation query returns?

Comment: How about `select @@read_only as col1;`

Comment: @Drew Yes this will have the same effect as `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'read_only'`, but how do I force the pool to evict a connection if `read_only` is `ON`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following validation query can be used:

```sql
select case when @@read_only = 0 then 1 else (select table_name from information_schema.tables) end as `1`
```

If the database is running in read-only mode, the query will fail with

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Since *Amazon Aurora* sets `innodb_read_only` but not `read_only` on the reader endpoint in a cluster, the validation query can be rewritten as

```sql
select case when @@read_only + @@innodb_read_only = 0 then 1 else (select table_name from information_schema.tables) end as `1`
```

Inspired by [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/78596/74223) answer.